# Mass of silver iodide that dissolves in ammonia

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, equilibrium

> What mass of $\ce{AgI}$ will dissolve in $\pu{1.0 L}$ of $\pu{1.0 M}$ $\ce{NH3}?$ Neglect the change in concentration of $\ce{NH3}.$
> Given: $K_\mathrm{sp}(\ce{AgI}) = \pu{1.5E-16};$ $K_\mathrm{f}(\ce{[Ag(NH3)2]+}) = \pu{1.6E7}.$ Atomic masses of silver and iodine are $\pu{108 u}$ and $\pu{127 u},$ respectively.

For this question I combined two reactions and wrote

$$K_\mathrm{eq} = K_\mathrm{sp} K_\mathrm{f},$$

but after that I think some data is missing, so I'm stuck here.

Comment: Can you elaborate your working?

Comment: Please  note that MathJax, as the name implies, is used to typeset in math mode. It makes no sense to enforce `\text{…}` on everything in math mode. While this issue has been fixed, please visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [this page](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/) and [this one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/) on how to format your future posts better with MathJax and Markdown. As for the question, it would be nice to see your thoughts beyond generic formula appearing out of nowhere.

Comment: There is enough data, try again and more. Provide details of your work. The site policy is to refuse solving such tasks for users unless sufficient explicit effort is provided.

Comment: We will show you the way. Try first to see that when $\ce{AgI}$ gets dissolved, most of the silver ions are transformed into $\ce{[Ag(NH3)2]^+}$ ions, so that the concentration in iodide ion is $\ce{[I^-] = [Ag^+] + [Ag(NH3)2]^+}$. Now the residual $\ce{[Ag^+]}$ is negligible, and the concentration of the complex is equal to $\ce{[I^-]}$. As a consequence you can deduce $\ce{[Ag^+]}$ from the solubility product. Draw then the concentration of the complex, and here you are.

Comment: I doubt that the solubility/formation product constants are given without dimension. Please cite the source and quote the exercise verbatim. Also, include **all** your work attempting the problem. In this case, write down the combined reactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the above answer is correct. I will show my process:

We have $\ce{K_\mathrm{f} = \frac{[Ag(NH3)2+]}{[NH3]^2[Ag+]}} = \pu{1.5E-16}$

and $\ce{K_\mathrm{sp} = \frac{[Ag(NH3)2+]}{[NH3]^2[Ag+]}} = \pu{1.6E7}$

Set up mass balance: $\ce{[I-] = [Ag+] + [Ag(NH3)2+]}$. Since $\ce{[Ag+]}$ is relatively small, we can assume $\ce{[I-] \approx [Ag(NH3)2+]}$.

That means $\ce{K_\mathrm{sp}\cdot K_\mathrm{f} = \frac{[Ag(NH3)2+]^2}{[NH3]^2} =} \pu{2.4E-9}$.

Now, we can set $\ce{NH3} = 1-x$, and $\ce{[Ag(NH3)2+]} = x$.

Solving for $x$ gives $x = \pu{4.899E-5 M}.$

Based on $\ce{[I-] \approx [Ag(NH3)2+]}$, $\ce{[I-]} = \pu{4.899E-5 M}$.

This correlates with a mass dissolved of $\ce{AgI}$ of $\pu{0.0115g}$.

Answer (score 0):

Here we have to assume that $\ce{[Ag(NH3)2^+] \approx [I-]}$:

\begin{aligned}
\ce{AgI (s) + 2 NH3 &<=> [Ag(NH3)2]+ + I-}\\
K_\mathrm{f} K_\mathrm{sp} 
  &= K_\mathrm{eq} 
   = \big[\ce{[Ag(NH3)2]+}\big][\ce{I-}]\\
\implies \pu{2.4E-9 mol2//L2} 
  &= \big[\ce{[Ag(NH3)2]+}\big]^{2} 
   = [\ce{I-}]^{2} 
   \qquad\because \ce{[Ag(NH3)2^+] \approx [I-]} \\
\implies [\ce{I-}] 
  &\approx \pu{4.89E-5 mol//L} \\
\implies n(\ce{AgI}) 
  &= \pu{4.89E-5 mol}\\
\implies m(\ce{AgI})
  &= \pu{4.89E-5 mol} \times \pu{235 u}
   = \pu{0.01149 g}
\end{aligned}

A mass of $\pu{1.1E-2 g}$ silver iodide dissolves.

Comment: No ! $K_f K_{sp}$ is not eqial to $\ce{[I^-]^2}$, as stated. It is equal to  $\ce{\frac{[I^-]^2}{[Ag^+]}}$

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry! On Chemistry mathematical and chemical expressions can be formatted using MathJax (and LaTeX Syntax).  If you want to know more, please have a look [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) and [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/4945). We prefer to not use MathJax in the title field, see [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/149/4945) for details. *I have cleaned up the format as best as I could, added units here and there, but it is unfortunately far from correct.*